# getElementById not working on IE 11: HTML5 <article> element

Tags: javascript, php, html, getelementbyid, semantic-markup

I'm currently building out a new website, and naturally, Internet Explorer is giving me trouble. I have some Javascript that's intended to reveal an element with an onclick.

It works exactly as intended on other browsers, but testing on IE 11 has lead me into one headache after another.

Internet Explorer is driving me nuts while I figure this out. A live example for the page effected is here: http://beerworld.sandbox.nikijones.com/whats-on-tap/

The elements effected by the bug are generated here:

```
<? foreach($beer_array as $beer){
                    $post = $beer['beer'];
                    setup_postdata( $post );  
                    $post_slug=$post->post_name; ?>
                    <article id="board-<? echo $post_slug; ?>" class="tap-board" >
                        <span class="tap-board-head">
                            <? $logo = get_field('logo');?><img class="board-logo" src="<? echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="<? echo $logo['alt']; ?>" /><h1><? the_title(); ?></h1>
                        </span>
                        <div class="row stats">
                            <? $brewery = get_field('brewery'); if(!empty($brewery)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                                <h3>Brewery:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $brewery; ?>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                            <? $style = get_field('style'); if(!empty($style)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                                <h3>Style:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $style; ?>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                            <? $color = get_field('SRM'); if(!empty($color)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                                <h3>Color&nbsp;Rating:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $color; ?>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                            <? $location = get_field('location'); if(!empty($location)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                                <h3>Location:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $location; ?>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                            <? $ABV = get_field('ABV'); if(!empty($ABV)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                                <h3>ABV:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $ABV . "%" ; ?>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                            <? $IBU = get_field('IBU'); if(!empty($IBU)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                                <h3>Hop:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $IBU; ?>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <? $desc = get_field('description'); if(!empty($desc)){ ?> <div class="col">
                            <h3>Description:&nbsp;</h3><p><? echo $desc ?></p>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                            <? $taste = get_field('tasting_notes'); if(!empty($taste)){ ?> <div class="col">
                                <h3>Tasting&nbsp;Notes:&nbsp;</h3><p><? echo $taste ; ?></p>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                            <? $food = get_field('food'); if(!empty($food)){ ?> <div class="col">
                                <h3>Food&nbsp;Pairing:&nbsp;</h3><p><? echo $food; ?></p>
                            </div> <? } ?>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                <? } ?>
```

And the script that only partially executes is here:

```
<script>        

    function boardswap(slug){   
        /* This function is for changing active taps, continued from the tap() function */

        var board_ID = "board-".concat(slug);
        var tap_ID = "tap-".concat(slug);

        /* Chalk Board Section */
        var activeBoard = document.getElementById(board_ID);
        activeBoard.style.height = 'initial';
        activeBoard.style.overflow = 'unset';
        activeBoard.style.opacity = '1';

        /*Display*/
        document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').style.height = '800px';
        document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').style.minHeight = 'fit-content';
        document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').classList.remove("rotated");
    }


    function tap(slug){

        var board_ID = "board-".concat(slug);
        var tap_ID = "tap-".concat(slug);

        /* Chalk Board Section */
        document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').classList.add("rotated");
        var boards = document.getElementsByClassName('tap-board');
        for (var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
            boards[i].style.height = '0';
            boards[i].style.overflow = 'hidden';
            boards[i].style.opacity = '0';
        }

        /* Taps Section */

        var taps = document.getElementsByClassName('tap');
        for (var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
            taps[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/tap.png)';
        }

        var activeTap = document.getElementById(tap_ID);
        activeTap.style.backgroundImage = 'url(<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/tap-active.png)';

        /* Pause before continuing */
        setTimeout(function(){ boardswap(slug); }, 1000);
    }

    </script>
```

All lines seem to trigger propperly with exception of the fact that on internet explorer, the article remains hidden by a height of zero.

These are the 3 PHP Files for the page to be absolutely thorough:

HEADER.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title><? the_title(); ?> - Beer World</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css">
       <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
       <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
       <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
       <![endif]-->
       <!-- WP Head Includes -->
     <?php wp_head(); ?>

       <!-- Fancy Box Image Lightbox -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

       <!-- Google Analytics Code -->
          <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
            <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-118283566-1"></script>
            <script>
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());
                gtag('config', 'UA-118283566-1');
            </script>

       <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
          <!-- No code yet -->
  </head>
  <body id="body" <? body_class(); ?> onscroll="scrollHead();">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <video id="bgVideo" preload autoplay muted loop >
        <source src="/wp-content/uploads/053119795-beer-bubbles-and-foam-slow-mot_H264_420-1.mov">
        <source src="/wp-content/uploads/Beer-Bubbles-and-Foam-Slow-Motion.ogg" />
        <source src="/wp-content/uploads/Beer-Bubbles-and-Foam-Slow-Motion.mp4" />
    </video>
    <div id="site-wrap">
    <div id="bg-gradient">
        <!-- Background Orange Gradient -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <header id="header">
            <div id="social">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/beerworldnewwindsor/" ><img src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/social-fb.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/beerworldstore2" ><img src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/social-twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
                <a href="#" ><img src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/social-li.png" alt="Linkedin" /></a>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                <!-- Button Created from Codepen By Collin Smith: https://codepen.io/collinscode/full/JLXJZY -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler back" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="hamburger();">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                        <div class="btn1 btn">
                            <div class="bar-container">
                                <div class="bar1 bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar2 bar"></div>
                                <div class="bar3 bar"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </button>
                <? $headArgs = array('menu' => 'Header Menu' ,
                                     'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav nav-fill' ,
                                     'menu_id' => '' ,
                                     'container' => 'div' ,
                                     'container_class' => '' ,
                                     'container_id' => 'HeaderMenu' ,
                                     'before' => '' ,
                                     'after' => '' ,
                                     'link_before' => '' ,
                                     'theme_location' => 'Header Menu',
                                     'link_after' => '');
                  wp_nav_menu($headArgs); ?>
            </nav>
            <img src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.svg" alt="Beer World Logo" id="navLogo" />
        <?/* * * NIVO SLIDER REPLACED BY REVOLUTION SLIDER ON JUNE 6, 2018 * * /
            <!-- Nivo Slider -->
            <? if(get_field('header_slider')){ ?>
                <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                        <? $images = get_field('header_slideshow'); ?>
                        <? foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                        <img src="<? echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" data-thumb="<? echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<? echo $image['alt']; ?>" class="nivo-img" />
                        <? endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </header>
      */ ?>

      <!-- Revolution Slider -->
      <? $term = get_queried_object(); ?>

      <? if(get_field('header_slider', $term)){ 
            $slides = strval(get_field('header_slideshow', $term));
            echo do_shortcode($slides);
        }else{ ?>
            <div id="spacer"><!-- No Active Slider For This Page --></div>
        <? } ?>
```

PAGE TEMPLATE:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: What's On Tap
 * 
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Beerworld
 * @since Beerworld 2.0
 */
?>

<? get_header(); ?>
</header>
<script>        

function boardswap(slug){   
    /* This function is for changing active taps, continued from the tap() function */

    var board_ID = "board-".concat(slug);
    var tap_ID = "tap-".concat(slug);

    /* Chalk Board Section */
    var activeBoard = document.getElementById(board_ID);
    activeBoard.style.height = 'initial';
    activeBoard.style.overflow = 'unset';
    activeBoard.style.opacity = '1';

    /*Display*/
    document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').style.height = '800px';
    document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').style.minHeight = 'fit-content';
    document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').classList.remove("rotated");
}


function tap(slug){

    var board_ID = "board-".concat(slug);
    var tap_ID = "tap-".concat(slug);

    /* Chalk Board Section */
    document.getElementById('tap-beer-display').classList.add("rotated");
    var boards = document.getElementsByClassName('tap-board');
    for (var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
        boards[i].style.height = '0';
        boards[i].style.overflow = 'hidden';
        boards[i].style.opacity = '0';
    }

    /* Taps Section */

    var taps = document.getElementsByClassName('tap');
    for (var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
        taps[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/tap.png)';
    }

    var activeTap = document.getElementById(tap_ID);
    activeTap.style.backgroundImage = 'url(<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/tap-active.png)';

    /* Pause before continuing */
    setTimeout(function(){ boardswap(slug); }, 1000);
}

</script>

<main id="content-area"><?
if (have_posts()){
   while (have_posts()){
      the_post();
       $beer_array = get_field('beers');
        /* Beer Display Area */ ?>
        <div id="tap-beer-display" class="container" >
            <div class="row">
                <h2>
                    TRY ONE OF OUR 24 FRESH, DRAFT BEERS
                </h2>
            </div>
            <? foreach($beer_array as $beer){
                $post = $beer['beer'];
                setup_postdata( $post );  
                $post_slug=$post->post_name; ?>
                <article id="board-<? echo $post_slug; ?>" class="tap-board" >
                    <span class="tap-board-head">
                        <? $logo = get_field('logo');?><img class="board-logo" src="<? echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="<? echo $logo['alt']; ?>" /><h1><? the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </span>
                    <div class="row stats">
                        <? $brewery = get_field('brewery'); if(!empty($brewery)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                            <h3>Brewery:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $brewery; ?>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                        <? $style = get_field('style'); if(!empty($style)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                            <h3>Style:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $style; ?>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                        <? $color = get_field('SRM'); if(!empty($color)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                            <h3>Color&nbsp;Rating:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $color; ?>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                        <? $location = get_field('location'); if(!empty($location)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                            <h3>Location:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $location; ?>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                        <? $ABV = get_field('ABV'); if(!empty($ABV)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                            <h3>ABV:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $ABV . "%" ; ?>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                        <? $IBU = get_field('IBU'); if(!empty($IBU)){ ?> <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 stat">
                            <h3>Hop:&nbsp;</h3><? echo $IBU; ?>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <? $desc = get_field('description'); if(!empty($desc)){ ?> <div class="col">
                        <h3>Description:&nbsp;</h3><p><? echo $desc ?></p>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                        <? $taste = get_field('tasting_notes'); if(!empty($taste)){ ?> <div class="col">
                            <h3>Tasting&nbsp;Notes:&nbsp;</h3><p><? echo $taste ; ?></p>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                        <? $food = get_field('food'); if(!empty($food)){ ?> <div class="col">
                            <h3>Food&nbsp;Pairing:&nbsp;</h3><p><? echo $food; ?></p>
                        </div> <? } ?>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <? }
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="tap-click" >
            <h2>
                CLICK ON ANY TAP BELOW
            </h2>
            <div class="row" >
                <? foreach($beer_array as $beer){
                    $post = $beer['beer'];
                    setup_postdata( $post );
                    $post_slug=$post->post_name;?>
                    <div class="tap" onclick="tap('<? echo $post_slug; ?>')" id="tap-<? echo $post_slug; ?>" >
                        <? $logo = get_field('logo'); ?><img class="tap-logo" src="<? echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="<? echo $logo['alt']; ?>" />
                    </div>
                <? }
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tap-blurb" >
            <? the_content(); ?>
        </div>
 <? }
}
?></main>
<? get_footer(); ?>
```

FOOTER.PHP

```
</div>
<div id="foot">
    <img src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/left-wheat.png" alt="bottom left wheat decoration" class="wheat left" />
    <footer class="container">
        <nav class='col-12'>
            <? 
            $footArgs = array(
                'menu' => 'Footer' ,
                'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav' ,
                'menu_id' => 'foot-menu' ,
                'container' => 'div' ,
                'container_class' => '' ,
                'container_id' => 'footerMenu' ,
                'before' => '' ,
                'after' => '' ,
                'link_before' => '' ,
                'link_after' => '',
                'theme_location' => 'Footer Menu');

            wp_nav_menu($footArgs); 
            ?>
        </nav>
        <div class="row" id="foot-info">
            <div class='col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6'>
                <img id="foot-logo" src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Beer World Logo" style="width: 160px; max-width: 160px; min-width: 160px;" />
                <span style="display:block;"><span style="font-size:22pt;" >BEER WORLD</span> <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/323+Windsor+Highway+New+Windsor+New+York" style="color: white;">323 Windsor Highway • New Windsor, New York</a></span>
                <span><a style="color: white;" href="tel:8455612244">845.561.2244</a> | <a style="color: white;" href="mailto:Info@beerworld.com">Info@beerworld.com</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class='col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6'>
                <p style="text-align:right;">© 2018 BEER WORLD&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />WEBSITE DESIGN BY THE NIKI JONES AGENCY, INC.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <img src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/right-wheat.png" alt="bottom right wheat decoration" class="wheat right" />
</div>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
  });

//Navbar Hamburger Script
function hamburger(){
  var toggler = $('#header').find('.navbar-toggler');
  if (toggler.hasClass('active')) {
      toggler.removeClass('active');
      toggler.addClass('back');
    }else{
      toggler.removeClass('back');
      toggler.addClass('active');
    }
  }

var $document = $('#body'),
    $element = $('#header'),
    className = 'hasScrolled';

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 20) {
    // user scrolled 20 pixels or more;
    $element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
  }
});
</script>

<script src="<? echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/ada.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which `getElementById` is failing, what's the error message?

Comment: I don't see any closing `</article>` or `</div>` tags. Have you tried [validating your markup](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fbeerworld.sandbox.nikijones.com%2Fwhats-on-tap%2F)?

Comment: I appear to have left out some of the markup in my paste. I have closing tags, but missed them in my copying of the markup. This is my first question, so I'll see if I can edit the question, and if I can, I will include the php files themselves

Comment: have you tried using htm5shiv? (https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)

Comment: html5shiv is in there

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the begining of the page, so IE switches to 5.5 emulation, makes tag self-closing and you get an empty element.

Comment: Doctype is declared, I included the Header.php for clarity